# Como calcular total acumulado de 365 dias juntando dois anos diferentes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando verificar o total acumulado de um determinado valor, que começa em setembro de uma ano e vai até agosto do ano seguinte, e depois recomeça. Estou fazendo isso com uma série histórica longa, então seria n somas para vários dados.

Já tentei esse sql:

```
SELECT ad.cod, ad.data, 
       SUM(ad.value)
            OVER(ORDER BY ad.data ROWS BETWEEN 364 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_value
FROM mytable ad
```

Comment: Você tem duas datas e quer fazer o somatório de uma coluna entre essas datas? isso?

Comment: Tenho dados que vão de 2009 até 2015, ordenados por dia. Eu quero somar o total de setembro de 2009 até agosto de 2010, seguido de setembro de 2010 até agosto de 2011, e assim em diante

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    to_char(date_trunc('year', ad.data - interval '8 months'), 'YYYY'),
    sum(ad.value)
from mytable ad
group by 1
```